# Getting a ValueType from a Type

Tags: c#

My code:

```
Type type = GetType(long?);
```

or

```
Type type = typeof(long?);
```

given the "type" from that, how can I get the string "long?" back?

Answer (score 4):

You can't get what it was written with. It is just a language shorthand.

`ToString()` should produce "System.Nullable`1[System.Int64]"

If you need it as a string, you could build up a dictionary.

```
var types = new Dictionary<Type, string>(); 
types.Add(typeof(long?), "long?");
```

However, you can't detect this.

```
types.Add(typeof(System.Nullable<long>), "System.Nullable<long>");
```

since `typeof(long?)  == typeof(System.Nullable<long>)`

Comment: yes, that's the problem, I really need to get hold of that short hand for a type

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this

```
Type type = typeof(long?);
Console.WriteLine(type.FullName);
```

But you wont get the string Long as every primitives types have aliases.And these aliases dont show up on the Type system.

You should get System.Nullable`1[System.Int64] for this statement.You have to customize your code to get the proper output string

Comment: Sorry, yes, but it's the same problem.  I'll edit the question

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Name property of Type, but that's not going to return "long?". long is a language syntactic sugar over System.Int64 type.

Answer (score 0):

You want to ask the type for it's generic arguments, something like:

```
typeof(long?).GetGenericArguments().First().Name
```

However, this returns the system type name, not the c# name.

Ie, `Int64` not `long`

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible.

`Type type = typeof(long?);`

Is simply a different type than `ValueType`.

`System.ValueType` derrives from `System.Object`, not `System.Type`.

`long?` is just a fancy way of writing `System.Nullable<long>` therefore it's type isn't `long?`, if you want to get which type it is, then you'll have to parse it yourself.

If you want to get the Type from `System.Nullable<T>` to the Type of `T` then this code will work:

```
Type t = typeof(long?);
t = t.FullName.StartsWith("System.Nullable") ? t.GenericTypeArguments[0] : t;
// t == typeof(long);
```